# requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); causing the App to crash?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

The App crashs when I add this line

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

may be the solution is very simple, but i really dont know who to fix it.

Java code:

```
public class GLSurfaceCameraSurfaceDemo2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
FrameLayout fl01;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

}
```

}

XML File:

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fl01" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: you must call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before setContentView() .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you must call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before setContentView()...

```
public class GLSurfaceCameraSurfaceDemo2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
FrameLayout fl01;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

just do this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

you must declar `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`